# How to use CORS in django rest framework?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, fetch

I have used `django-cors-headers` for `CORS` but unable to get `CORS` to work in a right way.

Like from client end I can run code from any host that are not in ALLOWED HOSTS but the request still completes without any `CORS` error.

Can anyone tell me , how can I only allow whitelisted hosts?

My `settings.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

SECURITY_TRUE = True
SECURITY_FALSE = False

DEBUG = False

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True

SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True

SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 1 #31536000

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"] 

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # add rest_framework support to the project
    'rest_framework',
    # setting cors policy is needed to make calls from ui to api
    'corsheaders',
    'mauth'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # Add cors middleware
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'm.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

"""DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}"""


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ["POSTGRES_NAME"],
        'USER': os.environ["POSTGRES_USER"],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"],
        'HOST': os.environ["POSTGRES_HOST"],
        'PORT': os.environ["POSTGRES_PORT"],
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  # Tell Django where to look for React's static files (css, js)
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend/static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1',
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'mauth.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

For frontend I'm using:

```
  config["headers"]["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = ENV.API_URL
  config["headers"]["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = 'true'

fetch(ENV.API_URL+url, config)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything in you frontend with headers etc.
You just have to make sure that Django (the backend) allows request from the host that the frontend is running on.

You have added `'http://127.0.0.1'` which is the host of the backend, (if they're not running on same host but then you'd have to add the port?)

So with `django-cors-headers` you can do something like this:

Let's say backend is running on `api.mysite.com`
and that frontend is running on `mysite.com` (with HTTPS)

Then in `settings.py` add this:

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r'^https:\/\/mysite.com$',
]
```

and if you want to allow from localhost for development then also add, which will allow from localhost on any port:

```py
r'^http:\/\/localhost:\d+$',
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN = ['frontend_domain_here']
```

in `settings.py` to fix CORS issue, and as mentioned from Felix, you do not need to do anything in frontend about CORS issue, thus it can be fixed in backend always.